# Easier way to solve this mixed conditional Probability problem?

Tags: probability

The following is a solved sample problem in a Persian book. The answer of the book is very confusing and used lots of events. I tried to find an easier approach to solve it, but seems like a dead end.

> Suppose we have 2 boxes; A and B. Box A contains 3 white balls and 4
>   red balls. Box B has 3 red balls and 2 white balls.  We randomly
>   choose one of the boxes and pick a random ball out of it, then we put
>   it into the other box. After that, we pick 2 balls out of the later
>   box (in which we have just put a ball inside of it) randomly. What is
>   the probability that we have transferred a red ball in the first move,
>   given that the later 2 balls are white?

Here's the answer provided by the book:

$W_i$ is event of picking a white ball from box $i$  on the first move

$R_i$ is event of picking a red ball from box $i$ on the first move

$WW_i$ is event of picking two white balls from box $i$ on the second move

$A$ is event of picking from box A on first move

$B$ is event of picking from box B on first move

$D$ is the event that we are looking for

Then,

$P(D) = P(A∩D) + P(B∩D)=P(A)*P(D|A)+P(B)*P(D|B)$

where

$P(A)=P(B)= \frac{1}{2}$

and

$$P(D|A) = P(R_A|WW_B) = \frac{P(R_A)*P(WW_B|R_A)}{P(R_A)*P(WW_B|R_A)+P(W_A)*P(WW_B|W_A)}$$

$$= \frac{\frac{4}{7}*\frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}}}{\frac{4}{7}*\frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}}+\frac{3}{7}*\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}}}=\frac{4}{13}$$

also
$$P(D|B) = P(R_B|WW_A) = \frac{P(R_B)*P(WW_A|R_B)}{P(R_B)*P(WW_A|R_B)+P(W_B)*P(WW_A|W_B)}$$
$$= \frac{\frac{3}{5}*\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}}{\frac{3}{5}*\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}+\frac{2}{5}*\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}}=\frac{9}{21}$$

therfore

$P(D) = \frac{1}{2}*\frac{4}{13}+\frac{1}{2}*\frac{9}{21}=\frac{201}{546}=\frac{67}{182}$

Comment: what is the solution of the book?

Comment: @AdrianMachin Thanks for adding the book's method to the post. ... OK, I'm really confused now, since that method looks ok to me as well!! I'll add some thoughts to my post ... maybe someone who is better at conditional probabilities can see where the mistake (whether in the book's, or in my approach) is made. Agh!

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks for your patience and help. Indeed your method looks OK to me too. I'm just curious to know why do they differ.

Comment: @AdrianMachin OK, I found a mistake in the book's approach! See my post.

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks a lot! You're amazing! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bayes' Theorem:

Where:

$R1$ is event of transferring red ball on first move

$2W$ is event of picking two balls on second move

$A$ is event of picking from box A on 1st move

what you are looking for is:

$$P(R1|2W) = \frac{P(2W|R1) * P(R1)}{P(2W)}$$

where:

$P(2W) = P(2W|R1)*P(R1) + P(2W|\neg R1)*P(\neg R1)$

Also:

$P(R1) = P(R1|A)*P(A) + P(R1|\neg A)*P(\neg A)$

where

$P(R1|A) = \frac{4}{7}$

$P(R1|\neg A) =  \frac{3}{5}$

$P(A) = P(\neg A) = \frac{1}{2}$

and of course $P(\neg R1) = 1-P(R1)$

And finally:

$P(2W|R1) = P(2W|R1\land A)*P(A)+P(2W|R1\land \neg A)*P(\neg A)$

where

$P(2W|R1\land A) = \frac{2}{6} * \frac{1}{5}$

$P(2W|R1 \land \neg A) = \frac{3}{8} * \frac{2}{7}$

and

$P(2W|\neg R1) = P(2W|\neg R1\land A)*P(A)+P(2W|\neg R1\land \neg A)*P(\neg A)$

where

$P(2W|\neg R1\land A) = \frac{3}{6} * \frac{2}{5}$

$P(2W|\neg R1 \land \neg A) = \frac{4}{8} * \frac{3}{7}$

Plug this all in (and you get $\frac{2993}{8039}$) ...so ... yeah, not simple ... and I don't know how to make it simpler either.

**Addition**

OK, so my answer is not the book's answer, so (at least) one of the approaches is mistaken.  Which one? (or both?)

Frankly, I find the $D$ 'event' that the book talks about a little confusing as it is defined as 'the event we are looking for' ... so is that 'the event of having-picked-a-red-ball-on-the-first-move-given-that-two-white-balls-are-picked-on-the-second-move'? ... I mean, is that really an event?

OK, so the book says:

$P(D) = $

$P(D|A)*P(A) + P(D|B)*P(B) =$

$P(R_A|WW_B)*P(A) + P(R_B|WW_A)*P(B)$

But if I were to follow that method, and given that in general that:

$P(A|B) = P(A|B \land C) * P(C|B) + P(A|B \land \neg C) * P(\neg C|B)$

I would say:

$ P(R1|2W) = P(R1|2W \land A)*P(A|2W) + P(R1|2W \land B)*P(B|2W) =$

$P(R_A|2W \land A)*P(A|2W) + P(R_B|2W \land B)*P(B|2W) =$

$P(R_A|WW_B)*P(A|2W) + P(R_B|WW_A)*P(B|2W)$

so ... the book made a mistake (the book has $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ instead of  $P(A|2W)$ and $P(B|2W)$ in this last equation).  Conceptually, the mistake is that it treated $R1|WW$ as an event $D$, and so when it went from $P(D|A)$ to $P(R_A|WW_B)$, it basically did something like this:

$P(D|A) = $

$P(R1|2W)|A) =$

$ P(R1|2W \land A) =$

$ P(R_A|WW_B)$

The third step makes sense, and even though the first two steps *seem* to make sense, they really don't. In fact, this is a good example why you don't want to treat something like $A|B$ as an event!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. What is this symbol: ∧

Comment: It's Logical conjunction. Is that the same as Intersection (∩) in this problem?

Comment: @AdrianMachin  Yes, same idea. If you're used to $\cap$ please use $\cap$ instead. ... so was this simpler than your book's answer or not? ... And was it the same answer in the end?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you've chosen simpler events. I think my main problem is that I either confuse or forget events based on their letters. I'm trying to calculate based on your formulation, it should be 67/182.

Comment: I calculated the result of your formulation and it came out 2993/8039 which is 0.3723, but the answer of the book is 67/182 which is 0.3681. Why do the results are a bit different? @bram28

Comment: @AdrianMachin I would need to see how the book calculated their answer in order to make any meaningful comment about that ...

Comment: @AdrianMachin Wait, I just noticed I never gave you the formula for $P(2W|\neg R1)$ ... Or did you figure that one out yourself? You must have plugged in something ...

Comment: @AdrianMachin OK, I added the formula for $P(2W|\neg R1)$ to my post.

Comment: @AdrianMachin I finally went through the actual calculation myself ... and got indeed to 2993/8039 (good job figuring out $P(2W|\neg R1)$ yourself!) ...  OK, I will need to know what the book did in order to see why my answer is different than the book's answer.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question and added the answer provided by the book. @Bram28

Comment: I agree. That book makes me confused every time I read it, and I'm going to find an alternative for it. Your approach is much better in my opinion. Thanks a lot for your time and attention :) @Bram28

Comment: Would you please recommend me an alternative book? It's a pity that stackexchange doesn't have any private messaging features. @Bram28

Comment: @AdrianMachin Sorry, I don't know of any book ... all my knowledge and skills are from high school way back and (more currently) doing searches online when I can't figure out something myself.  And being on stack exchange certainly helps too, e.g. I learned something from analyzing the very problem you posted here! So thank you!